# Inserting datatime type column into date type column

Tags: sql-server

I want to get 29-01-2021 in column in MYTABLE.

It will works if I:

```sql
insert into MYTABLE (column)  -- datatype is date
select 
 Column  -- datatype is datetime for example 29-01-2021 15:07:56.000
from OTHERTABLE
```

Comment: I don't know where you got that syntax from, but it is *not* T-SQL. Provided you use an unambiguous format (`yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnnnnnn)`) for your literal string date and time value, SQL Server will be able to convert it implicitly.

Comment: are you sure you are using sql server ? This syntax is very strange for sql server

Comment: That is not MSSQL syntax, please update your database tag with the actual DBMS you are using *or* fix the sql syntax in the question.

Comment: i edited, sorry for little confusion

Comment: You you want to insert a constant date value, use the VALUES clause instead of selecting from another table. The syntax should be `insert into MYTABLE (TheDateColumn) values ('20210129')`

Comment: If both the columns are a date and time data type, @Mgkraft , then SQL Server would just implicitly convert the value; there would be no error. What are you *really* asking here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will truncate the time portion, leaving you with a date value:

```
insert into MYTABLE (column)  -- datatype is date
select 
 cast(Column as date)
from OTHERTABLE
```

Comment: hm, answer is the same, I was 30 seconds earlier, but you get the credits :)

Comment: what is diffrence beetwen convert and cast ?

Comment: Why explicitly cast though, if the source column is a `datetime`. `datetime` can already be implicitly converted to a `date` without error; the time portion would simply be truncated. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eeb82b87b5cb439542bcd38a8bbee419) The fact that the OP was having a problem suggests that their source column was *not* a `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to put a datetime value into a date column, this can be done but you will loose the time portion off course

```
insert into MYTABLE (column)  -- datatype is date
select 
 convert(date, Column)  -- datatype is datetime for example 29-01-2021 15:07:56.000
from OTHERTABLE
```